# How to create this view on css? or javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, vue.js

[image: Example image]

This is the display of my school link during the pandemic, I want to paste the css or javascript concept but i don't know how.

Comment: Can you please mention what you tried already?

Comment: I've never tried it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe this can help

```css
.message-box {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

.message-box .wrapper {
    max-width: 375px;
    display: flex;
}

.message-box .wrapper .content {
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px 1px #00000063;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 25px 15px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
.message-box .wrapper .content a{
        text-decoration: none;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.message-box .wrapper .content label {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #007bff;
    padding-bottom:5px;
    display:block;
}

.message-box .wrapper .content p {
    margin: 0;
    text-transform: f;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: gray;
}

.message-box .wrapper .icon-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.message-box .wrapper .icon-wrapper span {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background: #007bff;
    border-radius: 100px;
    display: table;
}

.message-box .wrapper .icon-wrapper span i {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 12px;
}

.message-box .wrapper .icon-wrapper:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 4px;
    background: #dee2e6;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-radius: 25px;
    top: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
    <!-- Jquery -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- FontAwesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">   
</head>
<body>
    <div class="message-box">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="icon-wrapper">
                <span>
                    <i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </span>
            </div>

            <div class="content">
                <a href="#" class="">
                    <label>info pembelajaran daring</label>
                    <p>selama masa pandemi pembela jaran</p>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```